# Create word2vec model in Spark with multiple columns as input and output using scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I have the following data in a spark dataframe called df.

```
id    q1                q2
0     "some text"       "some other text"
1     "even more text"  "more text"
....
```

I want to create a word2vec model and in the end be able to calculate the cosine similarity between the columns q1 and q2. The way I approached this problem is as follows:

Following the documentation provided by spark I used the tokenizer to split my sentences into words and then removed the stop-words. Eventually I have this df.

```
id    q1                q2                  filtered_q1_words      filtered_q2_words
0     "some text"       "some other text"   [some, text]           [some, other, text]
1     "even more text"  "more text"         [even, more, text]     [more, text]
....
```

Now my problem is that I don't know how to create a single word2vec model with input both columns that would also output the vector representations in two columns so I would be able to efficiently compute the cosine similarity between the two columns. Is something like this possible? I tried the following but this creates two different word2vec models.

```
val word2Vec_q1 = new Word2Vec()
  .setMinCount(0)
  .setInputCol("filtered_q1_words")
  .setOutputCol("q1_Word2VecFeatures")
  .setVectorSize(100)

val word2Vec_q2 = new Word2Vec()
  .setMinCount(0)
  .setInputCol("filtered_q2_words")
  .setOutputCol("q2_Word2VecFeatures")
  .setVectorSize(100)
```

What I would want is a hybrid of the above approach. Something like this (which doesn't work):

```
val word2Vec_q1q2 = new Word2Vec()
  .setMinCount(0)
  .setInputCol("filtered_q1_words")
  .setInputCol("filtered_q2_words")
  .setOutputCol("q1_Word2VecFeatures")
  .setOutputCol("q2_Word2VecFeatures")
  .setVectorSize(100)
```